# extracting/inserting alpha channel from bitmap

Tags: c#, aforge, alpha-transparency

I want to work with the `AForge.Imaging.Filter` library, but I can't because AForge doesn't support `alpha` channel. 
If I will extract the `alpha`, work with the `filters`, and insert it again, might it work?

if so, how do I extract the `alpha`, and insert it?